# Error while updating a document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having an admin portal in which I am handling all the collections that exist in my Mongo database. Now, I am building the update operations. I want to find a user that exist with his username and update the document with the changes that the admin performed.

For that reason, in my controller I have an endpoint which do the following:

```
exports.updateUser = async(req, res) => {
  try{
    var user = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      username:req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      email: req.body.email
    });
    const static_username = req.body.static_username;

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({static_username} , user, { useFindAndModify: false})
    .then(data => {
        if(!data){
          res.status(404).send({ message : `Cannot Update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`})
        }else{
          res.redirect('/admin');
        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).send({ message : "Error Update user information"})
    })
  } catch {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

It takes the changes that the admin has made from the body and it puts them into `user` object. I also set to the variable `static_username` the username before update in order to find the user I to make the update.

I am getting a response that exist inside the catch of the query:

```
{ message : "Error Update user information"}
```

Error:

```
MongoServerError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'
```

Any thoughts why found user doesn't get updated?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ username: static_username}` ? And why are you using `useFindAndModify` ? Its not supported anymore.

Comment: @zx01 It should be {"username": static_username}, but still doesn't work. Tried your advice also. :(

Comment: Inside first catch block, check `err`.

Comment: @zx01 I updated the post. I assume that I am trying to perform an update without editing the _id field which causes the error?

Comment: Since you are not trying to update `_id`, so it should be fine in my opinion.

Comment: @zx01 Nope I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried removing `useFindAndModify` ?

Comment: Yes I removed it. I didn't know that it was deprecated.

Comment: The issue is actually you are trying to send a complete `User` model which has `_id` set to zero. So instead of creating a new `User` object, send a normal object.

Comment: @zx01 Nailed it! I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a `User` object which has an `_id` field by default. So, unknowingly you are trying to modify the `_id` field and setting it to zero. To solve this, you can simply send a normal object.

```
var user = {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      username:req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      email: req.body.email
};
```

Comment: So as I can understand I was trying to create a totally NEW object and update the previous one with that. And by doing that the _id field was getting a "conflict" error?

Comment: Yes exactly. The `User` object will have all the fields from the `User` model. Even the fields which you are not sending will be set to zero or empty depending upon the data type. In this case, `_id` was getting set to zero object id.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the update input should contain only the fields you want to update.  if username is the unique id in you User model, you would need to delete it from the user object - `delete user.username` - before passing it to `findOneAndUpdate` because an id cannot be updated.  Also, as mentioned in the comments, try replacing the filter with `{ username: static_username}`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! A solution has been provided to the answers :)